# Turn Spark Stream from Socket into DataFrame

Tags: python, pyspark, spark-streaming

I established a socket connection with my SparkSession that is sending a row of a .csv-File to my Stream.

So far my (PySpark-) code looks like this:

```
stream = spark.readStream.format('socket').option('host', 'localhost').option('port', 5555).load()

stream.writeStream.format('console').start().awaitTermination()
```

This prints the lines of the .csv File in one column like this:

```
+-----------------+
|            value|
+-----------------+
|[2, C4653, C5030]|
+-----------------+
```

But what I actually would like to have is this:

```
+-----+-----+-----+
| col1| col2| col3|
+-----+-----+-----+
|    2|C4653|C5030|
+-----+-----+-----+
```

I would like to use this as a DataFrame to feed a ML-Pipeline with.

How can I process the incoming Stream Data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already has a Data Frame **stream**, which just need to change schema.

Just add this transformation after **load()** call:

```
 stream.selectExpr("split(value, ' ')[0] as col1","split(value, ' ')[1] as col2", "split(value, ' ')[2] as col3")
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but trying `.foreachRDD` I get an error saying that DataFrame object has no attribute 'foreachRDD ? any hints on how I can get my incoming string into the desired format?

Comment: I considered you are using stream from Spark Streaming. Since you already has Data Frame, it become easier. Updated the answer.